# With CircleCI, is it possible to share an executor between two jobs

Tags: circleci

I am rewriting my CircleCI config. Everything was put in only one job and everything was working well, but for some good reasons I want more structure.

Now I have two jobs `build` and `test`, and I want the second job to reuse the machine exactly where the `build` job stopped.
I will later have a third and four job.

My desire would be a line that says I want to reuse the previous machine/executor, built-in from CircleCI.

Other options are Workspaces that save data on CircleCI machine, or building and deploying my own docker that represents the machine after the `build` job

What is the easiest way to achieve what I want to do ?

Currently, I have basically in my yaml:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: cypress/base:14.16.0
    steps:
      - checkout
      - node/install:
          install-yarn: true
          node-version: '16.13'
      - other-long-commands

  test:
    # NOT GOOD: need an executor
    steps:
      - run:
          name: 'test'
          command: 'npx cypress run'
          environment:
            TEST_SUITE: SMOKE

workflows:
  build-and-test:
    jobs:
      - build
      - smoke:
          requires:
            - build
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done. Workspaces is the solution instead.

My follow up would be, why do you need two jobs? Depending on your use case, pulling steps out into reusable commands might help, or even an orb.